# Prolog Programming List Arithmetic

Tags: list, math, prolog

Here is my code to make a countdown procedure which when I type in `countdown(5,L).` should return 
`L = [5,4,3,2,1]` and `countdown(5,[5,4,3,2,1])` should return `true`.

The input `countdown(5,L).` returns

> ERROR: is/2: Type error: `[]' expected, found`[5,4]' ("x" must hold one character)

which shows me my program is beginning to create the list.

```
%countdown
countdown(1,[1]).
countdown(A,L) :-
    concat([],[A],Z),
    makeList(Z,A,List),
    L is List.

makeList(X,Y,List) :-
    N1 is Y-1,
    N1 > 0,
    concat(X,[N1],Z),
    List is Z,
    makeList(Z,N1,List).

concat([],Y,Y).
concat([H|X],Y,[H|Z]):-
    concat(X,Y,Z).
```

Comment: Although Eugene Sh. gave a good, concise solution to the original task, it doesn't explain your error. You're hitting an error, in part, because you're using `is/2` incorrectly. `is/2` is for evaluating arithmetic expressions on the right hand side and instantiating the variable on the left with the result. Instead, you should be *unifying*: `L = List` and `List = Z`. In fact, in your `countdown(A, L)` you could write `countdown(A, List)` and get rid of the `L = List`.

Answer (score 1):

Why so difficult?

```
countdown(1, [1]).
countdown(N, [N|T]) :-
    N1 is N-1,
    countdown(N1, T).
```

Comment: Thanks, I am over-thinking these problems!

Comment: Try `countdown(0, Xs)`. It does not terminate!

Comment: Of course it doesn't, since 0 is an illegal input. I've taken the requirements from the question. Additional tweaks can be applied.

Comment: You definitely do not understand non-termination. Seriously `countdown(1,Xs), Xs = []` loops, too. But it should fail

Comment: @false Ok, I see you are taking it personally for some reason. I'll see what I am doing about this.

Comment: The only thing, all these example have in common is that they are incorrect. And it would be an opportunity for you to look at it. Making errors has at least this advantage that you can learn from it,

Comment: @false: Given sufficient memory and time :), `countdown(0,Xs)` should *eventually* terminate. Always good to enforce domain constraints up front, though.

Comment: @NicholasCarey: There are several notions of non-termination. The one I am referring to means: If something does not terminate, there will always be a bigger computer that will be able to continue the loop. But certainly, on a material computer, memory-resources are probably the first constraint one will hit.

Answer (score 0):

Some comments on your code:

- **`countdown/2`, clause 2, line 1:**

  `concat([],[A],Z)` is completely unnecessary.
  At the end of this exercise, `Z` is unified with `[A]`.
- **`countdown/2`**, clause 2, line 3:**

  As was pointed out, `is/2` evaluates the right hand term as an
  arithmetic expression and unifies the result with the left-hand side.
  This should be `L = List`.

  Even better, just change the line above from `makeList(Z,A,List)` to `makeList(Z,A,L)`.

But this is overly complicated. If one was to take your general approach, you could do it thusly:

```
count_down(N,L) :- % To count down to 1 from N,
  integer(N) ,     % N must first be integral
  N > 0 ,          % and positive
  range(N,1,L).    % Then you just need to generate the desired range.
```

`range/3` could be implemented simply as this:

```
range( X , Y , [X]    ) :- X = Y .
range( X , Y , [X|Xs] ) :- X > Y , X1 is X-1 , range(X1,Y,Xs) .
range( X , Y , [X|Xs] ) :- X < Y , X1 is X+1 , range(X1,Y,Xs) .
```